# Spring - Character added between form submission and Model mapping

Tags: java, spring

I've been doing many forms, validated and mapped automatically by Spring, without any issue. But this time, a comma (',') character is added before one the fields sent by the form.

Here are the data sent by the form, as captured by Firefox (sorry for not being able to post an image, but StackOverflow does not allow it :

**identifiant: yyy**

And when putting a break point at the top of the method in the controller (first line) :

**identifiant = ,yyy**

Which means that the comma has been added by Spring. What could cause this kind of issue ?

My JSP :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <c:set var="identifiantErreur"><form:errors path="identifiant" /></c:set>
    <label for="identifiant">Identifiant</label>
    <form:input type="text" class="form-control ${not empty identifiantErreur?'erreurBorder':''}" id="identifiant" disabled="${not empty directionForm.identifiant?'true':'false'}" placeholder="Identifiant" path="identifiant" />
    <small class="erreurDescription">${identifiantErreur }</small>
</div>
```

My Controller :

```
@PostMapping("/direction/fiche/sauver")
@Transactional
public String postFicheDirectionSauver (@Valid DirectionForm directionForm, BindingResult bindingResult, @ModelAttribute("maPage") HashMap<String,String> maPage, @ModelAttribute("monUtilisateur") HashMap<String,String> monUtilisateur, Model model, RedirectAttributes redAtt) {
    System.out.println("Entry in IdentiteController - Ajout/update d'une direction en DB");
    System.out.println("Direction reçue: " + directionForm);
....
}
```

Already at the first line, directionForm contains the field WITH the comma

My model :

```
public class DirectionForm {

    private long id;

    @NotBlank(message="L'identifiant de la direction ne peut pas être vide")
    private String identifiant;

    ...

    public DirectionForm() {}

    public final String getIdentifiant() {
    return identifiant;
    }

    public final void setIdentifiant(String identifiant) {
    this.identifiant = identifiant;
    }

    ....
}
```

I get completely puzzled. Anybody has an idea about what's happening ?

Thanks to all !